# using pandas built-in functions and for statements to compute min and max values with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, max

I imported data and assigned it to a `pandas` DataFrame named `life_exp`. This is my code for reading in the DataFrame.

```
life_exp = pandas.read_csv('life_expectancy.csv')
life_exp = life_exp.dropna() 
life_exp = life_exp.set_index('Country')
```

I need to use `pandas` built-in functions and for- statements to compute the minimum and maximum values in each year and append them to the lists `min_per_year` and `max_per_year`, respectively. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: please show some sample data, thank you, also are the two lists just variables you are creating for the purposes of storing the information? wouldn't it be more prudent to store them in a dictionary so you know which value corresponds to each year?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to use pandas built-in functions and for- statements"? Is that a design-constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to accomplish this:

```
# Create sample data
life_exp = pd.DataFrame(data={'data': np.random.rand(100)}, 
               index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='MS'))

# Group the data by year and compute the min and max
df = life_exp.groupby(life_exp.index.year).min().rename(columns={'data': 'min'})
df['max'] = life_exp.groupby(life_exp.index.year).max().values
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           min       max
2000  0.008992  0.891971
2001  0.279533  0.995257
2002  0.015490  0.846069
2003  0.122584  0.981442
2004  0.027147  0.985625
2005  0.050786  0.906058
2006  0.036598  0.987301
2007  0.020434  0.988755
2008  0.405666  0.939106
```

Make sure your index is a datetime index:

```
life_exp.Country = pd.to_datetime(life_exp.Country)
life_exp = life_exp.set_index('Country')
```